# Как сделать интернет магазин с аккаунтом администратора, который может сам добавлять товары?

Tags: php, javascript, веб-программирование

Разрабатываю сайт интернет-магазина. В этом деле я недавно. Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы владелец аккаунта (только администратор) мог сам загружать товары на сайт, указывая цену, параметры и т.д., не работая с самим программным кодом.

Comment: скачайте cms установите на хостинг ...и грузите туда ваши товары ...понадобится сменить шаблон магазина есть специализированные сайты по продаже шаблонов под все cms купите установите новый и радуетесь жизни

Comment: если понадобиться загрузить за раз огромное кол-во товаров наймите спеца он это сделает сам

Comment: @Максим Ленский, сам сайт уже написан, мне осталась логика с авторизацией и пользователем, который сможет добавлять товары сам

Answer (score 2):

Есть куча готовых решений, которые можно спокойно (или относительно) использовать:

- Wordpress + WooCommerce
- Magento2
- Sylius (это фреймворк)
- ModX + MiniShop2

и т.п.

Посмотрите, оцените количество материала и его качество, актуальность, попробуйте, наконец.

Comment: Сам сайт уже написан, мне осталась логика с авторизацией и пользователем, который сможет добавлять товары сам

Comment: @Alone_Fox, тогда в чем проблема? Во-первых, делаете вывод товаров из БД. Во-вторых, делаете для этого редактор, где кто-то может добавлять данные товары. В-третьих,  делаете аутентификацию на сайте, по стандартной схеме пользователь-роль-связь_пользователь_роль. При входе в редактор проверяете, вошел ли пользователь и какие у него есть роли. Если вошел и ВАША_РОЛЬ, то ок, если же нет или роль не та - то тут по ситуации, не вошел - переход на страницу входа, если не так роль - переход на страницу 403. Вообще, тут много вариантов, в общем-то и описанный мной один из многих.

Comment: Сайт у меня есть только в виде оформления

Comment: Значит, просто сделана верстка сайта. Это значит, как минимум ModX + MiniShop2 это ваш вариант. Конечно, если ваш хостинг поддерживает PHP/MySQL. Вообще, думаю так же можно рассмотреть и вариант с Wordpress + WooCommerce. Так же, там же можно и реализовать все что я написал в своем первом комментарии.